# What does ' you can do me every day' mean?

Tags: slang

If a girl is talking to a guy that she says she doesnt trust very much,  and the guy says

'you can do me every day ... Is that enough proof'

What does that mean?

Comment: "she saids" ? Is there plural indication in English past tense? Am I learning something new today ?

Comment: Askers who do not bother to use proper punctuation are not serious in getting an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a site to ask advice for relationships.

Answer (score 2):

The mistrust here is that she suspects he will be unfaithful. "Do" is a slang term for having sex with. He is suggesting that if they have sex every day, it should constitute proof that he is not sleeping with other women.